# How to open .ipynb files with subprocess in Windows?

Tags: python, subprocess

I got stuck in trying to open `.ipynb` files with subprocess.
Here is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
def get_data() -> Union[str, os.PathLike]:
    with resources.as_file(
        resources.files("data_storage").joinpath("mydata.ipynb")
    ) as f:
        mydata_file_path = f
    return mydata_file_path


def open_data() -> tuple[Any, Any]:

    filename = get_data()
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        shell_process = subprocess.Popen(filename, shell=True)
    elif sys.platform == "darwin":
        shell_process = subprocess.run(["open", filename])
```

On MacOSX it works well, but on Windows it does not.

The error I get is

```
path-like args is not allowed when shell is true
```

but if I remove `shell=True` I get

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Along the same line I did for MacOSX, I also tried to use

```
    shell_process = subprocess.run(["start", filename])
```

but I end up in

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: you need to convert `filename` to a string. That should at least solve that particular error.  It really isn't clear what you are trying to do otherwise.